# ¿Cómo hacer un buscarv en R?

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio, busqueda

¿Cómo hacer un buscarv en R o llevar el valor de un df1 a otro df2 si el valor de la columna df2$Xz se encuentra también en el df1$Xy, pero el valor que quiero llevar es de la columna df1$Xw?
Suponiendo que:
df1 en la columna X1 tiene ID´s (pueden estar repetidos) y en la X2 tiene Precios, y también tiene más columnas que no son de nuestro interés.
df2 por ahora solo tiene la columna Y1 la cual solo tiene ID´s únicos, pero queremos traer el precio correspondiente del df1. Tengo idea que con merge pero al momento de ejecutarlo me pega todo y solo necesito como resultado el df2 con ID´s únicos y Precios obtenidos del df1
De antemano muchas gracias!!!

Por ejemplo si tenemos la Tabla A1 (donde se buscara para llevar el valor a la Tabla B)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y por otro lado tenemos la Tabla B, a la cual le queremos agregar una columna extra donde estén los Registros de la Tabla B. Sucede que quiero en la Tabla B tener ID unicos, pero también tendré un inumerable de de Tablas A las cuales iran desde A1,..., A300 entonces necesito llevar el registro en la Tabla B si en la Tabla Ax se encuentra el ID o no se encuentra.

Por ejemplo en la Tabla A2 pudiese ser

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo cual mi Tabla B quedaría así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cual ya contiene los ID únicos y el registro en de la tabla correspondiente.

El idea seria solo llevar la "asistencia" si estuvo o no tal ID en tal Tabla Ax, en la Tabla B, es decir llevar la asistencia con ceros y unos. En dicho caso la Tabla B quedaría así.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow, para que tu pregunta sea correctamente contestada, podrías darnos una muestra de tus df y el resultado esperado, así podemos entender mejor tu problema y ayudarte a resolverlo. [Cómo hacer un ejemplo reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Puedes probar la función  `left_join(df2, df1)` pero la columna de ids en `df1` y `df2` tienen que tener el mismo nombre. Sin una muestra de los datos no podemos dar una respuesta concreta como ya menciono Jilber, no es necesario que sean tus datos originales (quizá son confidenciales y no puedes compartirlos) en cambio puedes compartir un df con la misma estructura pero cambiando los datos.

Comment: Gracias Jilber y Rolando